# Multiple for loops for setting variables but only the first produces an effect

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here's my Windows batch file:

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') DO SET branchName = %%a
FOR /F %%a IN ('git rev-list --max-count^=1 %branchName%') DO SET localCommitId = %%a
FOR /F %%a IN ('git rev-list --max-count^=1 origin/%branchName%') DO SET remoteCommitId = %%a

@ECHO branchName = %branchName%
@ECHO localCommitId = %localCommitId%
@ECHO remoteCommitId = %remoteCommitId%
```

Here's the output I see when I run it:

```
>FOR /F %a IN ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') DO SET branchName = %a

>SET branchName = develop

>FOR /F %a IN ('git rev-list --max-count=1 develop') DO SET localCommitId = %a

>SET localCommitId = e4375fa4753b3956e1454020a812cc7591cf606e

>FOR /F %a IN ('git rev-list --max-count=1 origin/develop') DO SET remoteCommitId = %a

>SET remoteCommitId = e4375fa4753b3956e1454020a812cc7591cf606e

branchName = develop
localCommitId =
remoteCommitId =
```

I don't understand why `localCommitId` and `remoteCommitId` are empty despite the printed `SET` commands setting them to non-empty strings.

I guess the function of `git` commands is irrelevant to the question because I get the same problem if I replace them with, say, `ver`.

Comment: Try removing the spaces in your set command, example: `DO SET branchName=%%a`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add a little explanation as well.  If you would type `set branch` you would see `branchName = develop`.  Meaning the variable would actually be called with `%branchName %` and would give the value `develop`

Corrected code below.

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') DO SET branchName=%%a
FOR /F %%a IN ('git rev-list --max-count^=1 %branchName%') DO SET localCommitId=%%a
FOR /F %%a IN ('git rev-list --max-count^=1 origin/%branchName%') DO SET remoteCommitId=%%a

@ECHO branchName = %branchName%
@ECHO localCommitId = %localCommitId%
@ECHO remoteCommitId = %remoteCommitId%
```